# Why am I getting "method without body" error when using Groovy Grape?

Tags: groovy, groovy-grape

Below is a code snippet and below that is the error. Am I doing something wrong that's obvious? I'm very new to Grapes.

```
   @Grab('com.microsoft:ms-sql-server-jdbc-dependencies')
    GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
    import groovy.sql.Sql

    println "Hello World"
```

org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
cfwdUpdate.groovy: 1: You defined a method without body. Try adding a body, or d
eclare it abstract.

at line: 1 column: 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed the `@` off

```
@GrabConfig(systemClassLoader=true)
```

Comment: Makes me look like a dummy. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Steve no worries, we've all been there :-)